# What happens if you dont scale box2d Pixels per Meter?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Do you have to scale pixels per meter? Can you make a game not using this but just using larger numbers? Will it effect how it looks when transferring between phone(android and ios) and computer?

Comment: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Answer (score 1):

Because of terminal velocity the objects will have a maximum speed of, say, 10 meters per second (I don't know the exact numbers). This would look fine if 1 meter was like 10 pixels but if 1 meter is 1 pixel it would be really slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the camera size
So you can directly set the values without converting them to meter

```
    @Override
public void create(){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(40,40 * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
}
@Override
public void render(){
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```